# componentWillReceiveProps and callback issues

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've got a big issue - probably a lack of understanding - in React. I've got a child component that makes a callback and has a componentWillReceiveProps function. The issue is that I cannot write on the text input the child is holding. I'll explain myself better in code.

**The problem**

I have a child with a text input. That child is inside his parent.

I need to:

- Type manually on the text input.
- Notify the parent that the text was changed.
- Modify the input from the parent under certain circumstances.

**The child**

Has a text prop for the text to display.
textChanged is the callback the parent will suscribe to.

**The parent**

Contains the child, has a function for the child's callback that does not update the child's state and holds a button to modify the child's text.

**The issue**

If I write text into the input, it doesn't work well.
If I remove the callback calling in the child (the this.props.textChanged(event.target.value); part) the input works well but the parent doesn't receive child updates.
If I remove the componentWillReceiveProps part, I cannot update the child's text from his parent.

You can play with the code snippet - it "works".

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    
var Child = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        text: React.PropTypes.string,
        textChanged: React.PropTypes.func
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return ({
            text: this.props.text
        });
    },
    handleChange: function (event) {
        if (event.target.value != null) {
            this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
            if (this.props.textChanged !== undefined) {
                this.props.textChanged(event.target.value);
            }
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.text != this.state.text) {
            this.setState({
                text: nextProps.text
            });
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input className="form-control" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            );
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        childText: React.PropTypes.string,
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return ({
            childText: this.props.childText,
            stateChangingProperty: true
        });
    },
    handleTextChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({
            stateChangingProperty: !this.state.stateChangingProperty
        });
    },
    handleButton: function () {
        this.setState({
            childText: "SOMETHING NEW"
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child text={this.state.childText} textChanged={this.handleTextChange} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleButton}>Write SOMETHING NEW on child</button>
            </div>
            );
}
});

    ReactDOM.render(<Parent childText="text" />,
                    document.getElementById('container')
    );
    
    
    </script>
```

**The question**

How can I achieve the desired behaviour? Is my aim wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure of what you're trying to do, but I'd get your *Parent* component to choreograph the rules and handle events like text change and button clicks, just letting the Child component be effectively 'dumb', concentrating on rendering its data.

As an example, I've implemented this [here](https://jsbin.com/ducoguf/edit?js,output)

as you will see, most of the lifecycle methods in the *Child* component can be removed. Now if you need to apply any 'business logic' to amend what has been typed in, you can do this in the controlling *Parent* component's *handleTextChange* function (say, convert to upper case and set the state).

This container pattern is very common and idiomatic in React:
https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.jg5yiorko

Comment: Dammit. You're right. I got too complicated focusing on updating the state and bubbling the events when it's not needed at all. Just in case I'd need to add some logic to the handlechange directly on the child and then notifying the parent, how would you do it? It's just for the sake of curiosity.